# Cost for nested anti loop on Explain Analyze

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, explain

I am getting the followig output with explain analyze:

```
Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.00..36.92 rows=83 width=3) (actual time=0.303..1 0.631 rows=83 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on paises p  (cost=0.00..5.46 rows=246 width=3) (actual time=0.0 43..0.336 rows=246 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using ciudades_pkey on ciudades c  (cost=0.00..12.92 rows=192 width=3) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=246)
      Index Cond: (c.pais_codigo = (p.pais_codigo)::bpchar)
Total runtime: 10.897 ms
(5 rows)
```

I cant understand why is the loop anti join cost 36.92.

In other sites I have seen the formula for the loop: cost of upper scan + upper row * inner cost.

But I am getting a cost of 36.92, so no way.
How is the dbmanager resolving this query?

Comment: Which query? Which version of PostgreSQL? Which table definitions? Which sample data?

Answer (score 1):

See [initial_cost_nestloop](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c#l1644) and final_cost_nestloop in PostgreSQL source for the exact algorithm for how it's calculated.

The optimizer is taking into account the difference between first and repeated scans of the inner relation, and the fact that for anti-joins only the first match of the index scan may be processed. CPU costs for joining the two relations are added on top of the sub plan costs.

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking it was a simple calc. I am sure my teacher dont want to know about why applying a fuzz factor of 2.0. But thanks, beacuse comments on source code wil be usefull.